# LaTeXed "Lectures on characteristic classes"

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

I don't know if this is the right place to ask, but...

Is anyone interested in a LaTeXed version (by me) of "Lectures on characteristic classes" by Milnor in 1957?
Of course the successor "Characteristic classes" has been around for almost 50 years, but as late Andrew Ranicki has listed the mimeographed notes in his online libarary, a LaTeXed one may have some value.
If you are interested in obtaining a copy, please let me know.

Comment: Yes I would be very interested!

Comment: Well, how can I send you a copy? May  have your mail address? Or any better idea?   And if you like, I can send you the TEX files as well (so you can correct the typos that have slipped out my proofreading effort.)

Comment: Sent the pdf and TeX files.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. I hope they may be of some value to you.

Comment: Perhaps the best way to make these widely available, as that seems to be your goal, would be to place them on a web page somewhere from which interested readers could download them.

Comment: A web page？  Well, I will look for  a free blog or something like.  Or will DropBox do if  post the address here?

Comment: one can make it an arxiv.org preprint.

Comment: places like github.org are natural places to keep such content.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not really a question at all. The poster is simply sharing their (valuable) work typesetting Milnor's book with the community.

Comment: Yes, the arxiv is better than a web site. My brain must be running a decade slow today.

Comment: Does the Arxiv accept papers submitted by third parties?

Comment: @GregFriedman I don't think that arXiv is for these purposes, although I see many lecture notes published there. Or rather, it might be better to have a section of "notes" on arXiv, and the timestamp does not seem to be important in this case.